# A function out of the matrix?

Tags: matrices, relations

I have a table of relations between various foods (each with each). Maybe that could be defined as a matrix. Here is a small 4 x 4 example:

```
            Rice    Soup    Ice cream   Salad
Rice        0       1           2       1
Soup        1       0           2       2
Ice cream   2       2           0       2
Salad       1       2           2       0
```

(The higher the value/distance, the less the compatibility between foods.)

My question is, is there some way to get out of such a relation table/matrix a unique function/formula?

Maybe such a function could define some pattern how these relations are set?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to notice is that the elements of a matrix are described by rows and columns and, in your case, are equal to a single integer. So, your function will be of the form $f(x,y)=n$. It would be valid to define the function on a case-by-case basis, for all elements but you can tidy it up slightly.

The matrix is symmetric across the main diagonal, so $f(x,y)=f(y,x)$. The main diagonal is $0$, so $f(x,x)=0$. Aside from that, every element of the matrix is $2$, except for $f(\text{'rice'},\text{'soup'})$, $f(\text{'rice'},\text{'salad'})$ and the corresponding inputs with $x$ and $y$ swapped. This defines the function fully:

$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}0,&y=x
\\
1,&x=\text{'rice'}\ \text{and}\ y=\text{'soup'},\ \text{'salad'}
\\
&\text{or}
\\&x=\text{'soup'},\ \text{'salad'}\ \text{and}\ y=\text{'rice'}
\\
2,&\text{else}
\end{cases}$

The definition would likely be even simpler if the foods are indexed.

Regarding whether there's a unique formula: no, since the function can be expressed in different ways. The function may be unique depending on the definition of the range and domain.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your solution looks very good and I suppose this can be applied **only** to those "foods" that have values from 0 to 2.

This 4 x 4 matrix was only a sample of the whole one with number of all possibilities around 30 (x 30).

Yes, the elements (values) are integers, but not always single; they will be probably from 0 to 25.

How would a function look like in this case? Still feasible?

Should it be more helpful I could add a big matrix as an image or Excel file.

Thank you once again.

Comment: As I said, the function can be defined on a case by case basis. $f(x_1,y_1)=a_1,\ f(x_1,y_2)=a_2\ldots$. And then, it can be simplified with whatever patterns are present. It is always possible to define a function between the position of the element in a finite matrix and the value of the element. It doesn't matter what number the element of the matrix, that doesn't impede any definition of the function. For your larger matrix, you can use the tips I've given to define a function.

Comment: OK. I see. I suppose I asked again as English is not my primary language and math is also not my number one _talent_. I hope you understand. Thank you once again.